# Alternatives to using absolute paths in included php files

Tags: php, include, absolute-path

I have a file called "header.php" that I am including on every page on my site and this file contains links to other files on my sever like css files, jquery plugins, etc.. and right now I am using absolute paths for those links so they will work with files that are  not in the same directory as the header.php file and this works, but as you can see in the example below, things start to get really hard to manage if you your header.php file contains lot's of links (which mine does) so I would like to know if there are any other alternatives to using absolute paths in the header.php file like I have done here.

**header.php**

```
<? 
 $base_url = "http://example.com";
?>
    <html>
      <head> 
       <title> <? echo($title); ?> </title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<? echo($base_url); ?>/styles/some_css_file.css" media="all"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<? echo($base_url); ?>styles/another_css_file.css" media="all"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<? echo($base_url); ?>styles/another_css_file.css" media="all"/>
        ...
        ...
        ...

        <script type="text/javascript" src="<? echo($base_url); ?>/scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<? echo($base_url); ?>/scripts/some_jquery_plugin.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<? echo($base_url); ?>/scripts/another_jquery_plugin.js"></script>
        ...
        ...
        ...
      </head>
```

**Some file which includes header.php**

```
<? 
  $title = "some page title";
  include("header.php"); 
?>

      <body>
        PAGE CONTENTS
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: I suggest you turn [`short_open_tag`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag) off immediately and start using full `<?php` tags instead. You are writing code that is not very portable...

Comment: I just added the short tag here in this example to make it easier to read. I never use short open tags for my real work. Thx tho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the HTML base tag to define the base of your site.

```
<base href="<?php echo $base_url; ?>" />
<link rel="style.css" />
```

Comment: This method seems to work and cleans up the code nicely, Are there any caveats that I should be aware of from using this method?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. I use a combination of this and a technique I'm about to shamelessly plug my own site on - http://bit.ly/MPls0E . Using that code and base has been really good for making sure all included CSS / JS are normalized.

Comment: Thanks, I have been testing it for about an hour now and have not found any negative side effects so I will go with this method as it's much cleaner then the way I was doing it before.

Answer (score 1):

Absolute path is the way to go here. But, if you have a lot of links to print, it can be simplified by storing the paths in an array and looping through the array.

```
$base = "http://www.example.com/"
$links = array( "styles/file1.css", "styles/file2.css", ... );

foreach ( $links as $link ) {
    echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="' . $base . $link . '" type="text/css" media="all" />';
}
```

As a side note, what you have isn't great practice. It would be better and more efficient for you to try and combine some of those files as this will reduce the amount of HTTP requests the browser has to make to your server. http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#num_http

Answer (score 1):

I had the same doubt in one of my projects and i've done as the code bellow. As the paths start with "/", the file will be found based in the root directory and in this case isn't necessary to specify the domain, it will turn the things easier for maintenace and prevent problems if you will do rewrite of URLs using ([mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)). Hope it can help you too!

```
<html>
  <head> 
   <title> <? echo($title); ?> </title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/styles/some_css_file.css" media="all"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/styles/another_css_file.css" media="all"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/styles/another_css_file.css" media="all"/>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/some_jquery_plugin.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/another_jquery_plugin.js"></script>
  </head>
</html>
```

Comment: Trying this on my local server WAMP did not seem to work for me. Not sure how it would work on a NIX system tho.

Comment: @nosx, Maybe it happens because of some security setting in your local environment, but check if the paths are correct. If you [see this page](http://evomaster.com.br/), note the source code, i've used exactly as i said you and it works perfectly in all browsers. The strange is that i've used it in local server WAPP (with Postgres database) and works fine.

Comment: This wouldn't work if the base URL is not at the root of the domain. For instance, if he is using http://localhost/site/ as his root, it would fail.

Comment: @kingcoyote, It will be necessay only to analyse the correct path, buty it should works.

Comment: If you analyze the correct path and just prepend all of them, you end up with exactly what the question is trying to avoid. This answer assumes that the site must be at the root domain, and based on nosx's comment on this answer, I don't think that is the case.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct answer to your question, but it may help you.

If you are including that many css and JS files you should look into using Minify.  Minify will take a bunch of css/js files and compress/combine them into one file, which will greatly speed up the loading of your site.

Using this could also help with your path concern, as you can specify directories and groups very easily.

You can find information about it here:  [Minify](http://code.google.com/p/minify/)